# Ideal Architecture for Django Projects

Tags: django

I'm getting into a rather extensive project and it popped into my head that I don't know what the accepted\proper architecture for a Django is these days.

I'll describe what prompted this question.  I am making a, what I think is a simple web site that, for all intents and purposes, is made for small companies, or even single entity LLC type companies.  In this project the front page is a simple sell of the company with some additional access for customers and employees.  Employees would log in, change\adjust\add contacts\companies\address etc.  I have this part all done, and I was about to move on to the next part which is filling out of reports.  This particular company will have two types of reports - consultation reports and service reports.

Now with where I am right now, I could continue to build on the current app\template, or I could start another app.  Staying within the current app would certainly seem to make things easier, but definetly not cleaner.  So what do you all do?  How do you structure your projects?  What are the general accepted conventions for decisions like this?

Thanks!